# Can't connect to wifi-connected server from wifi-connected client on the same network

Tags: wireless-networking

This question is a likely duplicate of [Can't connect to local server from other devices (connected via wifi) when the server is connected via wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/703522/cant-connect-to-local-server-from-other-devices-connected-via-wifi-when-the-s), which never received an accepted answer.

I have a Linux server, currently connected to the network via wifi. It works and is accessible (for instance, via ssh) from outside of my home network via a dynamic DNS service and router-based NAT and port forwarding. The router is a Linksys EA4500.

Local PCs wired to the router can connect via ssh successfully, though they must use the local IP (192.168.1.122, static via DHCP reservation at the router), because the router won't route internal traffic to its external IP. Fair enough, that's fine.

Local devices logged into the same wifi network as the server can't reliably connect. I just rebooted server, router AND wifi-connected PC, and several minutes later the PC was able to connect successfully...but prior to the reboots, connections failed (no route to host), and had been for several days. Having seen this pattern before, I'm fairly certain they're going to start failing again.

My thoughts are trending in the direction of this having something to do with DHCP renewals, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

**Commenter Questions:**

*"What does "can't reliably connect" mean?"*

When it stops working, attempts have the appearance of routing failures. Pings time out, most other protocols report 'no route to host', server logs show no connection attempt.

*"Does the server have both Ethernet and WIFI Interfaces?"*

Not any more; it's running on WIFI because the onboard Ethernet interface died during a lightning storm and the OS no longer recognizes it as being present.

*"Please provide the output of ifconfig and iptables."*

```
    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
            loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 31149  bytes 5871934 (5.5 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 31149  bytes 5871934 (5.5 MiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.1.122  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
            inet6 fe80::5627:1eff:fe1a:7535  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 54:27:1e:1a:75:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 2063063  bytes 379558678 (361.9 MiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 784726  bytes 119478321 (113.9 MiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Omitting `iptables` for now because when connections fail, no connection attempt is logged (iptables never has a chance to act on the attempt).

*"Do you have a single router performing the duties of access point as well, or do you have multiple routers, or separate router and access point? What IP addresses are you using for various devices, and how are they assigned? A good diagram with all the devices and IP addresses may be helpful."*

More detail on this when I'm physically present. But there's a cable modem and a separate router/WAP behind that. Router is doing DHCP on 192.168.1.*. Port forwarding from cable modem to router to server. Cable modem isn't in pure bridge mode (instead, it's doing DHCP with the router as its only client) because a bunch of stuff fell apart when I tried that (possibly oddness in the ISP's auth requirements) and I haven't wrestled with it because it wasn't a problem, but that might no longer be the case.

Comment: What does "*can't reliably connect*" mean? Can a client connect unreliably? Can it ping the server? Can server ping the client? Does ssh fail on timeout? Does server refuse the connection?

Comment: Does the server have both Ethernet and WIFI Interfaces ?  Please provide the output of ifconfig; iptables -vnl; route -n

Comment: Do you have a single router performing the duties of access point as well, or do you have multiple routers, or separate router and access point? What IP addresses are you using for various devices, and how are they assigned? A good diagram with all the devices and IP addresses may be helpful.